# Get/Assign IP addresses assigned by the DHCP sever with DLink switches in between

Tags: ip-address, dhcp-server

In our office the setup is like we have a UBUNTU server with DHCP Server connected to all the PCS via 24 port and 8 port DLink switches. How can I find all the PCS(with client name, ip and mac address)in the network??

When I do "vi /var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases", I get all the ip addresses for the switches.

I have used "arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet" to get all the IPs and MAC Addresses in my local network. I couldn't find any option to diplay client name.

Also I would like to assign particular IP for a particular PC. I have done the changes in the dhcp.conf file but it is not working as they are not directly connected to DHCP-server(DLink switches in between). How can I assign IPs for PCs in this kind of setup.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you use VLANS ? If not, the DHCP server should answer, log and provide an IP to each machine asking. The switches should propagate the request to the server without filtering it. It is strange that your DHCP server don't log the connections. Maybe there is another DHCP server on your network, and yours is not used.

Check the logs of DHCP server (in /var/log/). You will see the name of the machine if it is provided.